# THREE.js How to rotate CSS2D Text Labels

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I am using CSS2D to display text labels as in the [official example](https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label) and it works OK.

Now I want to perform a one-off rotation of some of the labels in the viewing plane.

I have tried applying a CSS transform to the div before making a CSS2DObject out of the div.

But it doesnt seem to be working (the labels are still horizontal).

Here is my code (for a single label):-

```
var myDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
myDiv.className = className;
myDiv.textContent = labelStr;
myDiv.style.marginTop = '-1em';
var degrees = 45;

/* *** These do not work ***

myDiv.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)'; 
myDiv.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)'; 
myDiv.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)'; 
myDiv.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)'; 
myDiv.style.transform       = 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)'; 
*/

var myLabel = new CSS2DObject( myDiv );             
myLabel.position.set( dX, dY, dZ ); 
//myLabel.rotateZ( degrees * Math.PI/180 ); //... *** Does not work ***

scene.add( myLabel );
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see what it's being done by [`CSS2DRenderer`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js), you´ll understand why it´s not working. Basically `CSS2DRenderer` is rewriting exactly those properties in the style every render loop.

```js
    var element = object.element;
    var style = 'translate(-50%,-50%) translate(' + (vector.x * _widthHalf + _widthHalf) + 'px,' + (- vector.y * _heightHalf + _heightHalf) + 'px)';
    element.style.WebkitTransform = style;
    element.style.MozTransform = style;
    element.style.oTransform = style;
    element.style.transform = style;
```

So you have one option in my humble opinion, apply the transformation to a div inside the one that is managed by `CSS2DRenderer`. I did it in one of my projects...
[image]

See below... The one with `class="label3D"` is the one managed by `CSS2DRenderer` (equivalent to your `myDiv`), and its children is the one that I create explicitly to apply the transformation. The result in the html would be like this...

```html
    <div class="label3D" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(487.583px, 205.32px); z-index: 36;">
        <div style="transform: rotate(45deg)">
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-yellow" title="NOCOMPLIANT"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So in your code, you only need to append a new children div to your `myDiv` and apply the transformation to the children instead of to `myDiv`, and then it will be "respected" by `CSS2DRenderer`.

Comment: Wow that is some advanced jiggery-pokery, I tried it and it works. Thankyou so much!

Comment: Haha! That was driving me crazy while ago, so I did some reverse engineering (aka jiggery-pokery ) to find the reason CSS2DRenderer was overriding my transformation. That’s what stackoverflow was invented for, wasn’t it? Enjoy!