# THREE.js CSS2D Text Labels - Can they be intersected and identified by RayCasting?

Tags: css, three.js, raycasting

I have been developing a rough diagramming tool using THREE.js and have been using the THREE.js CSS2D facility to make (rotatable and MathJax-friendly) text labels for the diagrams.

I have implemented object picking for ordinary mesh objects (e.g. cubes, spheres, lines) using the [THREE.js raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster) and it works fine.   The mouse pointer changes to the text cursor when it is over a CSS2D text label.  However raycaster does not pick any of the CSS2D label objects. Instead it "sees through" the labels and will pick a mesh object if one happens to be on the far side of the label.

I wonder if anyone can tell me whether object picking for CSS2D objects is feasible and what I might need to do to get it working?

Comment: It is hard to imagine it without an example. Can you provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You can add event listeners to divs of CSS2DObject. AFAIK, `THREE.Raycaster` is not intended to work with CSS2DObject, CSS3DObject, as these objects don't have implementation of `raycast` method.

Comment: @adelriosantiago Thanks, I'm currently trying out Mugen87's answer. If that doesnt work I'll maybe make an MRE. In the meantime here are official THREE.js examples of :- [CSS2D labels](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=css2d#css2d_label) and [Raycasting](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=raycast#webgl_interactive_cubes_ortho).

Comment: @prisoner849. Thanks for your tips. Mugen87's answer reinforces them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instance of `CSS2DObject` is always a wrapper around HTML markup. That means you can simply add event listeners to the top most HTML element in order to detect interaction:

```js
const text = document.createElement( 'div' );
text.className = 'label';
text.textContent = 'MyLabel';

text.addEventListener( 'pointerenter', event => console.log( event ) );

const label = new CSS2DObject( text );
```

Using `THREE.Raycaster` is not supported with `CSS2DObject`.

Comment: That works great, thanks. I'm using the child_Div trick of Jcastro to enable label rotation ( see his answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839541/three-js-how-to-rotate-css2d-text-labels) ) so I have to add the EventListener to that child_Div instead. To retrieve the text of the label I use: ` event => console.log( event.originalTarget.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].data ) ) `.